# GnuPlot: splot binned data

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I am looking for a way to plot a heatmap based on (x,y,z) data, which is already binned and where the x and y values denote upper bin boundaries.

Up to now I use

```
set pm3d map corners2color c4
```

This forces each relevant datapoint to have a valid point adjacent (at least with z=0).

I need 0-values to be plotted white, which I have recently achieved via

```
set datafile missing '0.00000E+00'
```

Unfortunately this makes all zero-datapoints invalid so GnuPlot will not plot the outermost non-zero datapoints anymore.

Is there a way to tell GnuPlot to plot zero-values in white but erverything else with my palette defined?

My datafile is formatted like this:

1e-10 1e1 value
1e-10 1e2 value
1e-10 1e3 value

1e-09 1e1 value
1e-09 1e2 value
1e-09 1e3 value

1e-08 1e1 value
1e-08 1e2 value
1e-08 1e3 value

Thanks!

Comment: I was hoping that something like `set palette defined (-1 "red", -0 "black", 0 "white", 0 "black", 1 "blue" )` would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: What happens if you filter the values at `using` level: `splot 'data.dat' u 1:2($3==0.0?1.0/0.0:$3) with pm3d` ?

Comment: @bibi  Up to now I solved the problem by setting set palette defined (0 "white", 0.00000000000000001 "#000090", 1 "#000fff", 2 "#0090ff", 3 "#0fffee", 4 "#90ff70", 5 "#ffee00", 6 "#ff7000", 7 "#ee0000", 8 "#7f0000")